# How to show slider current value with Cloudflare Apps UI?

Tags: cloudflare, cloudflare-apps

My question is related to the development of a [Cloudflare app][1].

The options allow defining a slider with min and max values. However, when displayed, the slider does not show what the current value is. That's really annoying, especially if the slider controls an offset value where you need to know the pixel value.

Is there a property to control whether or not the current value is displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to use the slider option format and also have the value be presented. You could use one of the other number types to have the user able to set an option based on a specific number